Pentaho HTTP Post error "Name may not be null"
I have some issues with a HTTP post step in Pentaho. If I preview it works, and does the post acuratly, however when I properly run the transformation I get this error (in the HTTP post step). The thing is there is no name field at all in the HTTP step that corresponds to the issue.
I've tried to run a single post, multiple posts, iterrations. Same outcome when "Run", no error occures when I do a "preview". Changed the payload to minimum, etc. When I preview it post the action accuratly. I don't believe it is an issue of the payload it self, I think the step somehow bugs out.
I've tried Pentaho 9.0 and 9.4.
Error log:
2024/08/14 09:00:39 - Carte - Installing timer to purge stale objects after 1440 minutes.
2024/08/14 09:00:52 - Spoon - Running transformation using the Kettle execution engine
2024/08/14 09:00:52 - Spoon - Transformation opened.
2024/08/14 09:00:52 - Spoon - Launching transformation [true_post_iterrative]...
2024/08/14 09:00:52 - Spoon - Started the transformation execution.
2024/08/14 09:00:53 - true_post_iterrative - Dispatching started for transformation [true_post_iterrative]
2024/08/14 09:00:53 - url.0 - Finished processing (I=0, O=0, R=0, W=1, U=0, E=0)
2024/08/14 09:00:53 - Microsoft Excel input.0 - Finished processing (I=1, O=0, R=0, W=1, U=0, E=0)
2024/08/14 09:00:53 - Modified JavaScript value.0 - Optimization level set to 9.
2024/08/14 09:00:54 - Modified JavaScript value.0 - Finished processing (I=0, O=0, R=1, W=1, U=0, E=0)
2024/08/14 09:00:54 - Add constants.0 - Finished processing (I=0, O=0, R=1, W=1, U=0, E=0)
2024/08/14 09:00:54 - Merge join.0 - Finished processing (I=0, O=0, R=2, W=1, U=0, E=0)
2024/08/14 09:00:54 - HTTP post.0 - ERROR (version 9.2.0.0-290, build 9.2.0.0-290 from 2021-06-02 06.36.08 by buildguy) : Unexpected error
2024/08/14 09:00:54 - HTTP post.0 - ERROR (version 9.2.0.0-290, build 9.2.0.0-290 from 2021-06-02 06.36.08 by buildguy) : java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Name may not be null
2024/08/14 09:00:54 - HTTP post.0 -     at org.apache.http.util.Args.notNull(Args.java:54)
2024/08/14 09:00:54 - HTTP post.0 -     at org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair.<init>(BasicNameValuePair.java:59)
2024/08/14 09:00:54 - HTTP post.0 -     at org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.httppost.HTTPPOST.processRow(HTTPPOST.java:436)
2024/08/14 09:00:54 - HTTP post.0 -     at org.pentaho.di.trans.step.RunThread.run(RunThread.java:62)
2024/08/14 09:00:54 - HTTP post.0 -     at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
2024/08/14 09:00:54 - HTTP post.0 - Finished processing (I=0, O=0, R=1, W=0, U=0, E=1)
2024/08/14 09:00:54 - true_post_iterrative - Transformation detected one or more steps with errors.
2024/08/14 09:00:54 - true_post_iterrative - Transformation is killing the other steps!
2024/08/14 09:00:54 - Select values.0 - Finished processing (I=0, O=0, R=1, W=1, U=0, E=0)
2024/08/14 09:00:54 - Dummy (do nothing) 3.0 - Finished processing (I=0, O=0, R=1, W=1, U=0, E=0)
2024/08/14 09:00:54 - true_post_iterrative - ERROR (version 9.2.0.0-290, build 9.2.0.0-290 from 2021-06-02 06.36.08 by buildguy) : Errors detected!
2024/08/14 09:00:54 - Spoon - The transformation has finished!!
2024/08/14 09:00:54 - true_post_iterrative - ERROR (version 9.2.0.0-290, build 9.2.0.0-290 from 2021-06-02 06.36.08 by buildguy) : Errors detected!
2024/08/14 09:00:54 - true_post_iterrative - ERROR (version 9.2.0.0-290, build 9.2.0.0-290 from 2021-06-02 06.36.08 by buildguy) : Errors detected!

